# checking for a role in different server

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

i'm trying to check for a role in a different server, when the member has the role.
it sends the message in the supportguild
but whenever i try to use the command in other server's it just says i dont have the role

```
import {SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder,} from "discord.js";
import * as djs from "discord.js";
import { SlashBuilder } from "../../../components/CommandBuilder";
export default new SlashBuilder({
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("startsession")
    .setDescription("session")
    .addStringOption((option) => option
    .setName("invite")
    .setDescription("why")
    .setRequired(true)
    
    ),
  async run(client, int) {
    try {
     const supportGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('743089332486799560')
     const member = supportGuild?.members.cache.get(int.user.id)?.roles.cache.has("1011724141101064364") //i have the role in the server
     const channel = client.channels.cache.get("992978029884219392")
     const channel2 = int.guild?.channels.cache.get(int.channelId);
     const Options = {
      maxAge: 0,
      maxUses: 100,
  };
var invite =  await (channel2 as djs.TextChannel).createInvite(Options)
if(member) {
  const gra = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setColor(0x0099FF)
  .setTitle('A session is being hosted!')
  .setURL('https://discord.gg/' + invite)
  .setDescription('GameMaster: ' + int.user.username)
  .addFields(
    { name: 'GameMaster Invite', value: '' + await int.options.getString("invite"), inline: true },
    { name: 'Bot Generated Invite', value: 'https://discord.gg/' + invite, inline: true},
  ) //what it gives on the main server
  .setFooter({ text: 'i am wanted by several governments.' });
int.reply("alright bud, sending the invite");
(channel as djs.TextChannel).send({ embeds: [gra] })
} else {
  int.reply("You erm, apparently don't have the required role, This is a issue that has been bugging me lately.") //what it gives on other servers
}

    }   catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      // @ts-ignore
      await int.reply({ content: err.message });
    }
  },
});
///
```

Answer (score -1):

fixed it by changing `cache.get()` to `fetch()`

I guess it just didn't have the guild and role in it's cache, so i changed it to fetch.